# I am using document object model with some json data also and I get the error: TypeError: res.forEach is not a function at index.js:10

Tags: javascript, html, axios

I am creating a Project and I have a html and javascript file.
I use document object Model also. i am getting this error TypeError: res.data.forEach is not a function

Comment: We need more information and a specific question to be able to help. Please show what your current code is doing and explain what you would like it to do instead. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.)
I can say that javascript is expecting your variable "data" (a property of the object  called "res") to be an array and is unable to invoke the array-specific method called "forEach" on "data" because it is not an array after all.

Answer (score 0):

in this case `res.data` is an object thats why you get `TypeError: res.data.forEach is not a function` , try `res.data.data` and see whats coming from your server inside the data object